# How can microwave radiation penetrate through walls but visible light cannot?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Obviously cell phone microwaves can penetrate more than just the walls of the house or an elevator...etc, why can't visible light at any strength penetrate the same objects?

Comment: WElcome to PSE. What do you think? Have you tried exploring this site? http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod3.html It says, "As you move upward through microwaves and infrared to visible light, you absorb more and more strongly. " I bet you can find out why!